# Extract text between two unicode symbols using AppleScript or bash?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, bash

My goal is to take text from a standard .txt document, and use (preferably) Terminal or Applescript to extract text between the symbols `▶` and `•`. While there is only one `▶` symbol there are multiple bullet points, so being able to extract data between only the first bullet is vital. I am partially educated in the ways of bash, so explanation would help me out a lot, otherwise I might screw up. TIA, Jake

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  While I am not entirely convinced this question isn't off topic, I can tell you it is quite unclear as to what you are asking.  You want to extract text between symbols?  Where would this text go?  If it has to go from a "▶" to a "•", but there are multiple "•", what exactly does the script do with that conflict? What do you want to happen?  At minimum, you should clarify what you want even if this question does get migrated to another site.

Comment: Scripting questions are on-topic. Until the OP amends the question, let's assume they want to have the extracted text in a variable or the clipboard and that text should be extracted up to the first bullet only (it says so in the text actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs with Bash, but it evokes some Ruby code:

```
ruby - <<EOF
puts /▶[^•]*•/.match("▶the first •2•3•4•5•666643")
EOF
```

If you decide to use AppleScript, you have a lot of options for what to match against:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set var to "▶the first •2•3•4•5•666643"

    set output to (do shell script ¬
"ruby - <<EOF
    puts /▶([^•]*)•/.match('" & var & "')[1]
EOF")

    return output
end run
```

Alternatively, sed can be used, which is easier for working with files:

```
sed -E 's/.*▶([^•]*)•.*/\1/' filename.txt
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I am just confused about where to put the path for the file we would be extracting the text from. Once again, I am sorry, but i have little experience with anything other than bash. Thanks Again! Here is an [example](http://pastebin.com/6mBX231P) document of which i would be extracting data from.

Comment: @Jake No problem. I translated it into sed, so it should be easier to do file things now.

Comment: Do you realize that the output of your `ruby` command and `sed` command, against the same _input_ is different? That said though, the `sed` command is producing only the text between the ▶ and the first •, which is what was expressed in the OP, so you should just remove the `ruby` portion of the answer since it's not as user friendly as the `sed` command and it outputs the ▶ and the first •  with the text too.

Comment: @user3439894 I can alter my Ruby to output things the same as the sed command. There's no harm in showing both ways, in any case.

Comment: If you modify the `ruby` command so its output is the same and it takes the source file as an argument like the `sed` command does, then I agree keeping both is fine.  However, in its present form it's not practical.

Comment: @user3439894 I have edited it yet again. This time, I have shown a way to use the Ruby code in AppleScript, so it can be used with virtually anything and is therefore extremely practical.

Comment: Did you test the block of AppleScript _code_ you posted? The reason I'm asking is because, if I copy and paste the block of AppleScript _code_ you posted, as is, into the AppleScript Editor and run it, while it does compile, nonetheless it errors out and doesn't produce the expected result.

Comment: @user3439894 It is copied directly from where I was running it, and it runs when I copy it back there. I cannot explain why you are getting these errors, because I am unable to reproduce.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks so much! they all work perfect for me. Sorry for the trouble you had to go through to find the right one.